# Jenkins job dsl and MSTest integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mstest, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-mstest

Jenkins [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) plugin is an extremely nice way to store CI config in repo and vary it from branch to branch.

The question is - is there a natural or close to natural way to run MSTest tests, parse results and display them.

Right now I do a powershell call, but that gives me only logs, not UI integration.

```
def testSomeProjectJob =  job(testSomeProjectJobName) {
    steps { 
      powerShell("& ${vstest} '${root}/SomeProject/SomeProject.Tests/bin/Debug/SomeProject.Tests.dll' ")
    }
}
```

May be there is a publisher or a trick with templating, or some tips of writing a plugin to JOB DSL for that

---

UPD: final script template for MSTest and VSTest using [@daspilker answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684599/2687006), jenkins [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) and [archiveXUnit](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.archiveXUnit)

```
  job('RunTests') {
      steps {
           // VSTEST
           powerShell("& ${vstest} 'path/to/Tests.dll' /logger:trx ")
           // Or MSBUILD
            powerShell("& ${msbuild} /testcontainer:'path/to/Tests.dll' ")
      }
      publishers {
        archiveXUnit {
          msTest {
            pattern('**/*.trx')
            // deleteOutputFiles()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a PowerShell step is a good start. Install the [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) to parse and display the results. It can parse all sorts of test results including MSTest. And you can use the [DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.ArchiveXUnitContext.msTest) to configure the plugin.

Example:

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    powerShell('...')
  }
  publishers {
    archiveXUnit {
      msTest {
        pattern('path/to/test/results')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its for VSTest but I had to end up using the configure block to be able to use it in the DSL jobs.

`static Closure useVsTest(List<String> dlls) {
        return {
        it / 'builders' << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.vstest__runner.VsTestBuilder' {
            vsTestName 'VS 14.0'
            testFiles dlls.join('\n')
            settings ''
            testCaseFilter ''
            enablecodecoverage false
            useVsixExtensions true
            platform 'x86'
            otherPlatform ''
            framework 'framework45'
            otherFramework ''
            logger 'trx'
            otherLogger ''
            cmdLineArgs '/TestAdapterPath:"."'
            failBuild true
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: That's very handy!